# Could someone explain the Big Oh complexities for arrays to me? I'm not quite understanding how they work

Tags: arrays, algorithm, complexity-theory, big-o, time-complexity

I understand Linked List complexities for the most part. Accessing an item is O(n) in worst case because it may be at the end or not exist. Adding is O(1) to an unsorted Linked List because you can just add it as the head.

But for arrays, I'm confused. I've read a lot about how accessing is efficient (O(1)) but addition isn't necessarily, neither is deletion. Why is this?

Is it because addition isn't always at the end? There it would be O(1), right? But if it's at another point, you'd have to shift the items, which would be O(n)? And this is happening "behind the scenes" so to speak in a high-level language, right? It's moving memory locations and that's where the complexity kicks in?

Deletion causes there to be a gap I gather? And it has to fill it in?

Basically if I have an array with 10 items in it, and I go to add an item at the 5th index point, would it have to copy all the items from index 5 and higher to a one-higher index point, causing the operation to be O(n)?

Any clarification would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It sounds like your understanding is correct.  What is your question?

Comment: Please specify the requirements for the data structure, you seem to compare an unsorted list with a sorted array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inserting (into the middle of the array, say) is `O(n)` because, as you state, you need to move all the subsequent elements to the right.  So if you insert at the first position, you'll have to move all `n` of the existing elements over to make room, giving you a worst-case cost of `n`.  On average, assuming you insert at a random position, you're moving `(n/2)` elements.

Appending (to the end of the array) is also `O(n)` because it my require a re-allocation.  If your array exists in a chunk of memory that's been allocated to be bigger than the current size of the array this isn't a problem;  you just do a (constant time) write to the next location in memory.  But eventually you are going to run out of room.  Then you need to allocate a new hunk of memory that's bigger and copy all of the existing elements into it.  So your worst-case net cost is `n+1` (`n` copies, plus `1` append) which gives you your `O(n)`.  (There's also whatever behind-the-scenes cost you incur for allocating memory.)  To avoid this cost, many languages and libraries give you the option of pre-allocating space in an array to cover the maximum number of elements you expect to see in your application;  this ensures there won't be any re-allocation unless you end up adding more than the expected number of elements.

Deletion is `O(n)` because (as you say) you need to move everything after the deleted element back one space to the left.  If you delete from the first position, you'll have to move all `n-1` remaining elements over, giving you `O(n)` for your worst case.  (If you delete from the *last* position, that just takes constant time.)

Comment: So arrays do not like to have gaps in their memory locations? Is this ever done to speed up deletion complexity? Like, just leaving a gap there?

Comment: @DougSmith, one problem with leaving a gap is that you would need to have a way to identify the gap.  For example, in an array of positive integers a zero could indicate a missing value, but this would not work in an array of all integers.  Another problem is that the time to iterate through the array would not shrink when you remove an element, and this is related to difficulty knowing what the size of the array is at any time.  So no, unless you have a very particular application you won't usually see gaps.

Answer (score 1):

[Typically, an array is a data structure with a fixed length.](http://xlinux.nist.gov/dads/HTML/array.html) This characteristic has advantages and disadvantages.

An advantage of an array in comparison to a linked list is that you can access any item in the array in Θ(1) if you know it’s position inside the array. Depending on the internal order of the items in your array, searching for a specific value can be quite efficient, e.g. when the items are in sorted order, you’ll only need Ο(log *n*) with binary search in an array in opposite to Ο(*n*) for a linked list that requires linear access.

The main disadvantage of an array is that you need copy all items if you need to resize the array. So if you don’t want gaps in your array, any insertion and deletion operation requires Θ(*n*).